What is syncthing-resume?
I'm following a tutorial to install SyncThing and set it up. On Ubuntu, it says to install SyncThing like this:
sudo apt install syncthing

It then says to start the SyncThing service by running this command:
sudo systemctl start syncthing

However, I get this error when I run it:
Failed to start syncthing.service: Unit syncthing.service not found.

If I use tab-complete, I notice that this is a service:
sudo systemctl start syncthing-resume.service

So my question is, what is syncthing-resume?

It turns out, you should run sudo systemctl start syncthing@USERNAME , replacing USERNAME with your username.

You can use systemctl status <service> to see general status information for a service, or systemctl cat <service> to dump the unit file (and overrides, if any) for that service. Either of these when used for syncthing-resume, will show that the description of the service is:
Description=Restart Syncthing after resume


Your question is "what is syncthing-resume?". However, from what you describe, I rather suspect that your real problem is: how can I start the syncthing service?
I guess it will be enabled by default after you installed the syncthing package. The service, however, is syncthing@username, where username is your actual username. So check its status with the command:
systemctl status syncthing@$USER

(You can enter the command like this: the $USER part will automatically be substituted by the user name of the current user).
If disabled, then enable with the command
systemctl enable syncthing@$USER

You will need to provide your user password.
b.t.w., syncthing-resume.service is a service that makes sure that Syncthing is launched again whenever the system resumes from a sleep state. You can see the contents of the service with the command. It usually includes a short description.
systemctl cat syncthing-resume

